# Array not getting populated with new data

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, nsmutablearray, reload

In my app I am using an array to get some data inside the method but every time after adding the object to the array, I check its contents then always it shows me 0 objects inside the array and also after that I am reloading the table view but nothing is happening.no event are called. I am showing my code here:

**in .h file**

```
@interface ModalView:UIViewController

           <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate> 

{

NSMutableArray *imageName;

}


@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imageName;
```

**in .m file:-**

```
@synthesize imageName;

      - (void)viewDidLoad {

       [super viewDidLoad];

     imageName=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [tableView1 reloadData];

     tableView1.delegate=self;

     tableView1.dataSource=self;
}

-(void)searchImagesInCategory:(NSString *)string
{
    string1=string;

    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory= [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.sqlite"];


    //Open the database
    //might have to make database as property
    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &dataBase) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        NSString *strSQL = [[NSString alloc]init];

        strSQL = @"select ImageName from tblLanguageElement where Category='";

        strSQL = [[strSQL stringByAppendingString:string1] stringByAppendingString:@"'"];

        const char *bar = [strSQL UTF8String]; 
        if(sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, bar, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);
                NSString *string2=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
              // [imageName addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
                NSLog(string2);
                [imageName addObject:string2];
                [imageName retain];
            }

            //tableView1.delegate=self;
            //tableView1.dataSource=self;
            [self.tableView1 reloadData];
        }
    }
    //return 1;
    //[tableView1 reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    }

    cell.imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

This is my code. Why my array (imageName) is not getting the data inside the method and why table view is not reloading?

Comment: Is your query actually returning results?

Comment: instead of using column 0 try column one. I remember reading somewhere that they start at 1. COuld be wrong but worth a try

Comment: Just a comment, your string strSQL appears to be leaked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're instantiating your array in viewDidLoad, but what happens if you add it at the beginning of the method `-(void)searchImagesInCategory:(NSString *)string`:

```
imageName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: then i am getting the value in teh array but i want to use this array in other methods also ,,so how can i access that if i write like this

Comment: and also i am calling that table view reload data but its also not working

Comment: That sounds really weird. What if you try copying the string that you get from SQL instead of using it directly. Perhaps: `[imageName addObject:[string2 copy]];`

Comment: I think you need to finalize the statement. IIRC, currently it is leaking objects because you aren't finalizing. `sqlite3_finalize(compiledInitStatement);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the object in your header file as nonatomic retain, then synthesized and allocated it in your implementation, you do not need to retain it each time you add something to it. You should try removing the `[imageName retain];`

Comment: Ok, how are you checking the count of the array, because i don't see any NSLog statements.

Comment: Oh, also just a side note, but in your tableView: method where you have [imageName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] you should make sure there is an entry at that index in the array, or you may get a bounds issue

Comment: i am just debugging the code and then found that my array shows me 0x0 whever i bring ym cursor to that